Find segment $AH$ in the figure below
Calculate AH if BC = 6m, CD = 9m and CL = 7m.
(Answer: 8m)

I try:
$\angle DEL = 360^o -(90^o + 60^o + 90^o ) = 120^o $
$\therefore \angle LEH = 60^o $
$\angle LAB = 360^o -(90^o +90^o +60^o ) = 120^o $
$\angle HAE= 180^o - 90^o -60^o = 30^o $
$ \triangle HAE? sen 30^o .AE = AH \implies AH = \frac{AE}{2}$


$\angle M = \angle N =  30^{\circ}$ and $\angle E = 60^{\circ}$(sum of $\angle$'s in $\triangle$)
$CM = CN = 14 , ML = NL = 7\sqrt3 , (30^{\circ} - 60^{\circ} - 90^{\circ} - \triangle)$
and $AM = \frac{16\sqrt3}{3}, EN = \frac{10\sqrt3}{3} , AE = 14\sqrt3 - \frac{26\sqrt3}{3} = \frac{16\sqrt3}{3}$
$AH = \frac{16\sqrt3}{3} \times \frac{\sqrt3}{2} =8$, $(30^{\circ} - 60^{\circ} - 90^{\circ} - \triangle)$

Thanks for hel...

Hint:



Extend AH and CB and let it meet at point M.
Then, Extend BC and HD and let it meet at point N.
Extend CL until meet the line segment CL at point O.
Let $BM=x,$ and $AM=2x.$
$CM=MO=CO=6+x$.
$OL=(6+x)-7=x-1$.
You can use the properties of the lengths in 30-60-90 triangles.
I think you can continue the rest of the solution by construct an equation for the lengths of $AO$ and $LO$ in triangle $ALO$, and find the value of $x.$
The rest of the solution:

 $$OA:OL=2:1$$ so $$6-x=2(x-1)$$ solve that $x=\frac{8}{3}$.

 $BC=9,$ so $NC=18$, $MN=24+\frac{8}{3}=\frac{80}{3}$
$MH=\frac{1}{2} MN =\frac{40}{3}$.

 $AH=\frac{40}{3}-2\times \frac{8}{3}= \frac{24}{3}=8cm$.


Thanks for help

@petaarantes I have added the rest of the solution.

I see..thanks.......
